# Result of findBySQL in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, where-clause, find-by-sql

Query **"SELECT * FROM uzytownik"** in phpMyAdmin gives me all recodrs from **uzytkownik** table. But this same query applied in yii controller gives me olny one (first) record. What is wrong?

```
class StronaController extends CController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new Uzytkownik;
        $wynik = $model::model()->findBySQL('SELECT * FROM uzytkownik');
        for($i=0;$i<count($wynik);$i++)
        {
            echo count($wynik).' '.$wynik ->imie.'<br>';
        }

    }
}
```

Output:
1 Jan

Query with WHERE conditions gives me also one record, but it should gives me three.

```
class StronaController extends CController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new Uzytkownik;
        $wynik = $model::model()->findBySQL('SELECT * FROM uzytkownik WHERE imie=:imie',array(':imie'=>'Jakub'));
        for($i=0;$i<count($wynik);$i++)
        {
            echo count($wynik).' '.$wynik ->imie.'<br>';
        }

    }
}
```

Output: 1 Jakub

```
class Uzytkownik extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
$wynik = $model::model()->findAllBySQL('SELECT * FROM uzytkownik WHERE imie=:imie',array(':imie'=>'Jakub'));
```

Know the difference between,

> `findBySql()` And `findAllBySql()`

Comment: Important is `$wynik[$i] -> imie` in loop